# error C2248 while using std::atomic<bool>::atomic

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, fix-protocol

Firstly, pardon me for the long post.

I am using boost::lockfree::spsc_queue to run on two separate threads to process FIX messages. I am using quickfix for converting FIX strings from a file to convert to FIX Messages. I want to be able to pass the queue as a pointer to both threads and a boolean value that indicates whether there are still messages to be processes.

I am getting the following error:

Please refer the code below.

It is based of an example in boost documentation. (Waitfree Single-Producer/Single-Consumer Queue)

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/lockfree/examples.html

I have been trying different ways to transfer the value of running and pqFixMessages to the two threads but nothing seams to work as of now. I will appreciate any suggestions.

```
'std::atomic<bool>::atomic' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::atomic<bool>
```

Description:

Producer thread reads a file, creates FIX messages and pushes them in the queue.

Consumer thread reads the queue and processes these messages. As of now, I am just displaying the session id's for debugging.

Main has a pointer to the queue that is passed on to both the threads.

Further Context: After this works, I want producer and consumer to be separate classes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <fstream>
#include <quickfix\Message.h>
#include <boost\lockfree\spsc_queue.hpp>


using namespace std;
using namespace boost::lockfree;

void producer(spsc_queue<FIX::Message, capacity<1024>> * pqFixMessages, std::atomic<bool> running) {
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream fixMessageStream(<filename>);
    FIX::Message currentMessage;
    while (fixMessageStream) {
        std::getline(fixMessageStream, line);
        try {
            // Erases the timestamp on messages
            currentMessage = FIX::Message(line.erase(0, 25));
            pqFixMessages->push(currentMessage);
        } catch (std::exception& ex) {
        }
    }
    running = false;
}

std::atomic<bool> done(false); 

void consumer(spsc_queue<FIX::Message, capacity<1024>> * pqFixMessages, std::atomic<bool> running) {
    FIX::Message frontOfTheQueueMessage;
    while(!pqFixMessages->empty() || running) {
        if (!pqFixMessages->empty()) {
            pqFixMessages->pop(frontOfTheQueueMessage);
            cout << frontOfTheQueueMessage.getSessionID() << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    spsc_queue<FIX::Message, capacity<1024>> * pqFixMessages = 
        new spsc_queue<FIX::Message, capacity<1024>>();

    std::atomic<bool> running(true);

    thread producerThread(producer, pqFixMessages, ref(running));
    cout << "Entered Producer Thread" << endl;
    thread consumerThread(consumer, pqFixMessages, ref(running));
    cout << "Entered Consumer Thread" << endl;

    producerThread.join();
    cout << "Joined Producer Thread" << endl;
    done = true;
    consumerThread.join();
    cout << "Joined Consumer Thread" << endl;

    delete pqFixMessages;

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::atomic`s are not copyable.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic)

Hence, passing them by value to a function is not possible.

This is for a reason. Usually, attempting to pass them by value indicates a programming error. They are typically used as synchronization primitives and you cannot synchronize anything with a copy.

Comment: ahh I see. Passing it as a pointer did the trick. But still want to understand that when I pass a reference to it 
    producerThread(producer, pqFixMessages, ref(running));
- does it create a copy of it or operates on the same object?

Comment: `std::ref` only takes care of not copying the object when creating the closure for the thread. The function that executes the thread still must not take its argument by value, or you will copy it here when launching the thread. Only if you have both the function parameter as reference _and_ the `std::ref` upon thread creation do you get true pass-by-reference.

Comment: Yeah - That makes sense. Passing both of them by reference worked. It was a bug. 

void producer(spsc_queue<FIX::Message, capacity<1024>> * pqFixMessages, std::atomic<bool> running) 

should be 

void producer(spsc_queue<FIX::Message, capacity<1024>> * pqFixMessages, std::atomic<bool>& running)